# Going Live - Any best practice check list and how to increase security on an MVC Site?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been building quite a few MVC based websites locally and am finally ready to deploy the first, but, I am getting rather nervous.

During testing, I noticed several things that worried me - I am using the default forms authentication with a few tweaks (although nothing to the underlining security).

I noticed that if I created a user in one application and logged in, then launched another application... it would keep me logged in`*` as the user from the previous application. The user doesn't even exist in the new application!

`*` - I used `[Authorize]` on controllers, and was surprised I could just get straight in without any sort of authentication

I assume it is because the cookie is being set for localhost instead of the application/port (although, not too much I can do about this in development).

Based on this, how secure is the default authentication?

`1.` Is there anyway to check from the code that the user doesn't have a "faked" cookie? / Check the user has logged in from my application?

`2.` I was just wondering if there are any sort of check lists or anything I can go through before deploying?

`Sort of - 3.`As of writing this, For question `1.` I am guessing I could add a column with a random number that is saved to the cookie, and then that number is checked every time any authentication is done... however, I did not want to start mucking around with the membership provider... but I think this could work. Is this a good idea?

Comment: For the first one. Probably you are using the same machinekey for every website. Use one machinekey for websites. this http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey is one of the millions sites that help you generate the key

Answer (score 0):

Try using IIS on your machine instead of VS Dev Server. Solves your problem 1.

Other than that I don't think you will need any extra effort to make default membership mechanisms of asp.net to make more secure if of course you don't need a real custom things to do in your projects. These things are around for a while now and I think they have been well tested in terms of security.

You just need to remember to put [Authorize] attribute to right places. If not on your controllers put them to right methods.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Web Authentication shouldn't be trusted for applications which contain truly sensitive information. That being said it's sufficient for most applications. Be sure to check your application as often as possible before **and after** release for XSS vulnerabilities.

Here is Microsoft's recommended "Secure yourself" list. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx

No matter how strong your authentication is, one small XSS mistake and a malicious user can do as they wish to your site, and your users data!

I recently read a good book: Worx Professional ASP.NET, it talks about these steps in more detail on securing yourself as well as exposing examples of problems. After reading this I was able to "deface and steal" my own sites information with relative ease, was a good eye opener on the importance of securing for XSS.